# UrlEncodedFormEntity doesn't encode underscore

Tags: java, android, http, url, apache-httpclient-4.x

I want to use a remote API from my Android device, but for some reason, the *UrlEncodedFormEntity* class doesn't transform the `_` with `%5f` like the remote API seems to expect. As a consequence, using this code:

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
nameValuePairs.add(
    new BasicNameValuePair("json", 
        "{\"params\":{\"player_name\":\"Toto\",
            \"password\":\"clearPass\"},
            \"class_name\":\"ApiMasterAuthentication\",
            \"method_name\":\"login\"}")
    );
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8));
ResponseHandler responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
httpClient.execute(httpPost, responseHandler);
```

send a post request to the server, with this content:

```
json=%7B%22params%22%3A%7B%22player_name%22%3A%22Toto%22%2C%22password%22%3A%22clearPass%22%7D%2C%22class_name%22%3A%22ApiMasterAuthentication%22%2C%22method_name%22%3A%22login%22%7D
```

I would like it to be like this (replacing the preivous underscore by %5F):

```
json=%7B%22params%22%3A%7B%22player%5Fname%22%3A%22Toto%22%2C%22password%22%3A%22clearPass%22%7D%2C%22class%5Fname%22%3A%22ApiMasterAuthentication%22%2C%22method%5Fname%22%3A%22login%22%7D
```

I don't have control over the API, and the official client of the API behave like this. It seems to be the expected behaviour for an [URL normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_normalization)

Am I missing something? I first thought it was an UTF-8 encoding issue, but adding `HTTP.UTF-8` in the constructor of `UrlEncodedFormEntity` doesn't solve the problem.

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT:** Finally, the problem didn't come from this unescape underscore. Even if the other client I tried to reproduce the behaviour escaped it, I only had to set the proper header:

```
httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

And the request worked just fine. Thanks everyone, and especially singh.jagmohan for his help (even if the problem was finally elsewhere)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"_" isn't a reserved symbol for urls.

setting : `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`'

should solve the problem. Otherwise you can try replacing it, if you really need this option:

```
String.Replace("_", "%5f");
```

See [percent encodeing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Character_data) , [replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29)

Comment: Your solution doesn't work, because when I replace **_** with **%5F**, the **%** symbol is then transcode to **%25**.
As a consequence, `player_name` become `player%255Fname` instead of `player%5Fname`

Comment: Well, finally I didn't had to replace it, you were right. The only problem was to set the proper header `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
The fact you said it shouldn't be replaced make me read more documentation about url escaping and look for another source of error.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ill add the solution to answer,for future reference. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code, it works for me.

```
try {
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(serviceUrl);
    MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity();
    // Also, in place of building JSON string as below, you can build a **JSONObject**
    // and then use jsonObject.toString() while building the **StringBody** object
    String requestJsonStr = "{\"params\":{\"player_name\":\"Toto\",\"password\":\"clearPass\"},\"class_name\":\"ApiMasterAuthentication\",\"method_name\":\"login\"}";
    multipartEntity.addPart("json", new StringBody(requestJsonStr));
    httpPost.setEntity(multipartEntity);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // add specific exception catch block above
    // I have used this one just for code snippet
}
```

**PS:** The code snippet requires two jar files **apache-mime4j-0.6.jar** and **httpmime-4.0.1.jar**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: *MultipartEntity* doesn't seem to be present in the *HttpClient* version embedded in the Android SDK. Have you tried from an Android project or from a Java Project?

Comment: This requires JAR files, apache-mime4j-0.6.jar and httpmime-4.0.1.jar. I sorry forgot to mention this, I will update my answer as well.

Comment: Even with this libraries, I still have the same problem: when I analyse the packets sent on my proxy, the underscore are still there (whereas the other client sent encoded underscore on my proxy).
Can the problem come from elsewhere?
(I run your code sample from Android Studio on Linux to my Android Nexus 5 phone)

Comment: No, I don't think so. 
What I could like to know is how could you tell it worked for you? You used a proxy or a network sniffer?
If this code worked for you (it transform '_' to '%5F', it means the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Actually, my server accepts JSON objects, I thought uploading it as part of multipart/form-data might help in your case as well.